# Общее количество распечатанных страниц за все время

Tags: java, принтер

В консоль необходимо выводить общее количество распечатанных страниц за все время но увеличивать значение не получается, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
public class Printer {
   private String queue = "";
   private int pendingPages = 0;
   private int pageHistory = 0;

   public void append(String textOfTheDocument) {
        append(textOfTheDocument,1,"");
    }

   public void append(String documentName, int pageCount) {
        append(documentName, pageCount, "");
    }

   public void append(String documentName, int pageCount, String textOfTheDocument) {
       queue = queue + "Имя документа: " + documentName + ", количество страниц: " + pageCount + " Текст:  " + textOfTheDocument + "\n";
       pendingPages += pageCount;

   }

    public int getPrintPageHistory() {
        return  pageHistory;
    }
    public int getPendingPagesCount() {
       return pendingPages;
    }

   public void clear() {
       queue = "";
       pendingPages = 0;
   }

   public void print(String title) {
        System.out.println(title);
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Нет документов на печать");
            System.out.println("Общее количество распечатанных страниц за все время: " + getPrintPageHistory());
            } else {
            System.out.print(queue);
            System.out.println("Общее количество страниц в очереди: " + getPendingPagesCount());
            pageHistory += pendingPages;
            clear();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При каких условиях не получается увеличивать счетчик?

Comment: `public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer document = new Printer();
        document.append("текст 1", 12);
        document.append("текст 2", 4);
        document.append("текст 3", 1, "Привет Серафим");
        document.append("текст 4",1);
        document.print("Очередь печати:");
        document.clear();
        document.print("Очередь печати:");
    }
}`

Comment: прошу прощения, забыл приложить main